# Android Studio - эмулятор запускается, но проекта в нем нет, так же и в genymotion

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, эмулятор

Android Studio - эмулятор запускается, но проекта в нем нет, так же и в genymotion эмуляторе. Эмулятор работает четко, но проект не открывает, даже стандартный "Hello world" который создается авто. при создании проекта. Ошибка в логах связано только со звукам при запуске в стандартном AVD самого Android Studio. Язык: Kotlin Genymotion: 3.0.4 VirtualBox: 6.1.0 Android Studio: 3.5.3 AVD: 29.3.4 OS: Windows 7 64-bit, i5-4460, RAM - 8GB

UPD: почему эмулятор не видит проект? хотя сам прекрасно работает.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
    package="com.example.kalkik">

    <dist:module dist:instant="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
    package com.example.calculator

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        fun setTextFields (str: String) {
            math_operation.append(str)
        }

        one_.setOnClickListener { setTextFields("1") }
        two_.setOnClickListener { setTextFields("2") }
        three_.setOnClickListener { setTextFields("3") }
        four_.setOnClickListener { setTextFields("4") }
        five_.setOnClickListener { setTextFields("5") }
        six_.setOnClickListener { setTextFields("6") }
        seven_.setOnClickListener { setTextFields("7") }
        eight_.setOnClickListener { setTextFields("8") }
        nine_.setOnClickListener { setTextFields("9") }
        nol_.setOnClickListener { setTextFields("0") }

        minus.setOnClickListener { setTextFields("-") }
        plus.setOnClickListener { setTextFields("+") }
        umn.setOnClickListener { setTextFields("*") }
        drop.setOnClickListener { setTextFields("/") }
        yaya.setOnClickListener { setTextFields("(") }
        yayy.setOnClickListener { setTextFields(")") }

        clear_text.setOnClickListener {
            math_operation.text = ""
            result.text = ""
        }

        cistka_.setOnClickListener {
            val str = math_operation.text.toString()

            if (str.isNotEmpty())
                math_operation.text = str.substring(0, str.length - 1)

            result.text = ""
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Android Studio - эмулятор запускается, но проекта в нем нет, так же и в genymotion эмуляторе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1067886/android-studio-%d1%8d%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d0%b2-genymoti)

Comment: так там ответа нет

Comment: И здесь не будет. Там зато есть вопрос.

Comment: можно по теме, если у Вас нет ответа, не зачем здесь флудить. спс

Comment: @User_Kotlin, во-первых я бы вам советовал придерживаться культурного поведения с потенциальными ответчиками вашего вопроса, во-вторых с тем количеством информации которую вы выдали довольно сложно дать хоть какой-то ответ, поэтому я бы вам советовал перечитать свой вопрос и постараться добавить больше информации, в-третьих попробуйте сбросить эмулятор до дефолта и запустить снова на нем приложение. Ваш вопрос будет закрыт если информации в нем не появится больше чем есть сейчас, вам будет неприятно и мнение о данном форуме останется не очень приятное. Давайте жить дружно :)

Comment: @User_Kotlin по теме еще в тот раз попросил показать манифест файл.

Comment: Добавил манифест, правильно?

Comment: @User_Kotlin, сразу извиняюсь что не дам ответа, т.к. судя по всем проект небольшой могу посоветовать создать проект заново и все классы и xml файлы перенести туда и не делать ничего в Manifest и прочих файлах в которых вы слабо разбираетесь. Просто судя по всему ошибка не стандартная и на её поиск уйдет неопределенное кол-во времени, а заново создав проект вы можете здорово это самое время себе сэкономить

Comment: @ДанилСычев, пробовал заново создавать, но проблема остается, эмулятор не видит проект... дело в том, что он не запускает ни один проект...

Comment: проблемку решил, спасибо всем.